# Joining a table to a polygon using Esri Insights for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-online, attribute-joins, spatial-join, insights-for-arcgis

I am trying to perform a many to one join using Esri Insights for ArcGIS. With in Insights I am trying to join a flow and pressure table to a polygon. Esri Insights does not allow for spatial joins or query tables so I am looking for a simple way to perform the join. The data format for the flow and pressure table is as follows Date, Time, Flow, Pressure and the field set up for the polygon is object id, shape, shape_Length, and shape_Area. The overall goal is to have the flow and pressure data appear in the attribute table of the polygon.

Is there a simple way I can format the data table or polygon to allow for the join ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you're using Insights for ArcGIS Online or Enterprise, but here is the workflow:

1. Create a common field in all three of your tables (including your feature class) to use for your relationship.
2. Create a **Relationship** using the steps in this [help topic](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/insights/enterprise/latest/create/create-relationships.htm)

Note: You can perform a spatial join in Insights using the [Spatial Filter tool](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/insights/enterprise/latest/analyze/spatial-filter.htm) or the [Spatial Aggregation](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/insights/enterprise/latest/analyze/spatial-aggregation.htm) tool.